# jQuery not: (this) exclude everything from a class except for the one called in a previous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, slidetoggle

Hey all,
I've got some hidden divs that are shown via a dynamic slideToggle function. Everything works great, but the divs are left shown when you click on other links. I'd like one div shown at a time. Clicking hides the others and shows the new one. It seems I can never get the full function correct!

Thank you for your time! I appreciate it immensely. Just a 'lil baby here.

HTML:

```
    <div id="nav">
        <div class="menu"><a id="show_work">WORK</a></div>
            <div id="work" class="sub">
                <p>hidden content</p>
            </div>
        <div class="menu"><a id="show_biography">BIO</a></div>
            <div id="biography" class="sub" >
                <p>hidden content</p>
            </div>
        <div class="menu"><a id="show_contact">CONTACT</a></div>
            <div id="contact" class="sub">
                <p>hidden content</p>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Javascript that works but leaves them all open:

```
$('#work, #biography, #contact').hide();
$('#nav .menu').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    return false;
}).next().hide();
```

Mangled conceptual Javascript of what I'd like:

```
$('#work, #biography, #contact').hide();
$('#nav .menu').click(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle(400);
    $('.sub not:(this)').slideUp(400);
});
return false;
});.next().hide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('.sub').hide();
$('#nav .menu').click(function() {
    $('.sub:visible').not($(this).next()).slideUp(400);
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    return false;
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EvilAmarant7x/wF9jy/) to watch it work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just write a function that hides all of the divs on any click:

```
function hideDivs() {
  $(".menu div").hide();
}
```

Then your clicks look like this:

```
$('#show_work').click(function() {
    hideDivs();
    $('#work').slideToggle(400);
});

$('#show_biography').click(function() {
    hideDivs();
    $('#biography').slideToggle(400);
});

$('#show_contact').click(function() {
    hideDivs();
    $('#contact').slideToggle(400);
});
```

This works by hiding all of the divs no matter what link was clicked. You could hide the non-target divs manually (shown below), but I think hiding them all is a good approach.

Alternative, (uglier and less maintainable - also needs logic to skip the slideToggle call if the "show div" is already visible):

```
$('#show_work').click(function() {
    $('#show_biography, #show_contact').hide();
    $('#work').slideToggle(400);
});

$('#show_biography').click(function() {
    $('#show_work, #show_contact').hide();
    $('#biography').slideToggle(400);
});

$('#show_contact').click(function() {
    $('#show_work, #show_biography').hide();
    $('#contact').slideToggle(400);
});
```

Comment: Seems like it would instantly make the open item close, then gradually open the new one. Would look a little weird. Shouldn't you slide close the open item while sliding open the new one?

Comment: Yes, you could slide instead of hide - it was more about the concept than a finished product.

Comment: This worked, but is kind of clunky. I updated my question with a simplified function. hopefully this helps clarifying what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

[The accordion control from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) seems like it would do what you're looking for.

Comment: way cool! never saw it.. unfortunately it leaves one open at all times (i'd like to start with them all closed) and conflicts with my layout (the hidden divs arn't directly beneath the corresponding link). tried jimmy-ing it.. but it wasn't smooth enough. also had this weird highlighting thing going on.

Comment: @technopeasant The accordion control has an option collapsible that allows all of the sections to be closed. But if it conflicts with other things you have, that wouldn't fix the issue.